# Saving state in a react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I´m building a react native app for my own use(for android), and I don´t get how to save the state of my app, since the idea is to save some text data in the phone.
I want to save some orders, which are going to be around 400-700 a year(i´m quite sure this wont increase), so I don´t think I really need like a server with a database.

I saw AsyncStorage but it looks like it´s intended for something else, like login tokens and stuff.
Would a text file(csv for example) do the job? Or how would you do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [RxDB](https://github.com/pubkey/rxdb) - A realtime Database for JavaScript Applications.
- [WatermelonDB](https://github.com/Nozbe/WatermelonDB) -  Next-gen database for powerful React and React Native apps that scales to 10,000s of records and remains fast.
- [realm](https://github.com/realm/realm-js) - An alternative mobile database to SQLite & key-value stores.
- [react-native-storage](https://github.com/sunnylqm/react-native-storage) - This is a local storage wrapper for both react-native(AsyncStorage) and browser(localStorage). ES6/babel is needed.
- [react-native-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage) - SQLite3 bindings for React Native (Android & iOS)
- [react-native-simple-store](https://github.com/jasonmerino/react-native-simple-store) - A minimalistic wrapper around React Native's AsyncStorage.
- [react-native-store](https://github.com/thewei/react-native-store) - A simple database base on react-native AsyncStorage.
- [react-native-easy-app](https://github.com/chende008/react-native-easy-app/blob/master/README.en-US.md) - This is a local storage wrapper for both react-native(AsyncStorage).

Check [awesome-react-native](https://github.com/jondot/awesome-react-native/blob/master/README.md#storage). This is list of libraries that can help solve much of your problems

Comment: Thanks for the info, I´m going to go with realm :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a server ,You can use firebase realtime database or firebase firestore.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I end up choosing realm since it fits better for this case.

Answer (score 0):

you can use redux-persist if using redux doesn't matter for you!